# Rectangle Layout in IOS Collage App

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, image-processing, quartz-core

I want to make a collage application like "Pic Collage"
https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/pic-collage/id448639966?mt=8

Here I am stuck in a functionality in which we can make collage for predefined rectangular layouts.
When we select any layout the pictures on screen automatically fitted in the selected layout design and layouts are dynamic with number of pictures on the screen.

Please suggest how this functionality of creating layouts and fitting images in the layout can be implemented?

Following is link to layout that I am looking for:
1. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ge4mhx9vkyb9s2n/IMG_4914.PNG

Comment: its a collection view my Frined. do searching about `UICollectionview` and try to implement its layout-methods.

Comment: @NitinGohel Thanks for the update. I have one more query that Can we make dynamic layouts in UICollection view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you going to use templates as shown in the application then you can be sure of how many grids would be needed. In that case based on the selected template you could use variations of UITableview and [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView). You can customize it according to requirement.

Also you could look into [Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH1-SW1).

I would have probably added multiple UIImageViews based on the templates and provide feature for addition of images by handling the touch event.